# Rails ajax 'like' button while iterating

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've got a list of `Vendors` that I'm iterating through as you can see in the below view. I'm trying to implement a 'favorite' or 'like' button for each vendor. I'm having some trouble getting it working. Here's my view:

`vendors/show.html.erb`

```
<% provide(:title, 'Stores') %>

<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>Store Name</th>
        <th>Store Address</th>
        <th>Favorite</th>   
    </tr>

    <% Vendor.all.each do |v| %>

    <tr>
        <td><%= v.name %></td>
        <td><%= v.address %></td>
        <td>
            <div id="like">
                <%= render 'layouts/like_button', :vendor => vendor %>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <% end %>
</table>
```

My controllers:

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @vendors = Vendor.all
    end
end

class LikesController < ApplicationController

    # respond_to :js

    def create
        @like = Like.create(likes_params)
        @vendor = @like.vendor
        render :toggle
    end

    def destroy
        like = Like.find_by_id(:id)
            like.destroy
        @vendor = like.vendor
        render :toggle
    end

    private

    def likes_params
        params.permit(:id, :user_id, :vendor_id)
    end

end
```

And my partial `_like_button.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_tag("/likes", method: "delete", action: "destroy", :remote => true) do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:id, vendor.likes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).id) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Unlike") %>
<% end %>
```

```
<%= form_tag("/likes", method: "post", :remote => true) do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:user_id, current_user.id) %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:vendor_id, vendor.id) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Like") %>
<% end %>
```

My toggle.js.erb file:

```
$("#like").html("<%= escape_javascript render('like_button') %>");
```

I'm getting this error currently: 'Couldn't find Vendor with id=vendor'
So somehow the word vendor is getting passed in as an id, but I don't know where or how to fix it. I haven't done much with ajax or javascript so I'm sort of green at this. I've been trying to follow the functionality of this sample app: https://github.com/sergeylukin/soquestion6482354/blob/master/app/views/products/show.html.erb

Help please? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT NOTES**

I've updated my code to reflect the changes I've made. I had to mix it up with the form as I couldn't get form_for to work while I was iterating. I can currently submit `likes` via ajax with the correct parameters, however I still can't submit `unlikes`. I'm also not seeing my page updated with new `likes` appended. As I said, I'm really green at js and ajax so I'm just not sure why. Thanks for the help!

**Model Update**

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many    :inventory_items
    has_many    :items, through: :inventory_items
    has_many    :shopping_lists, through: :inventory_items

    has_many :likes
    has_many :liking_users, :through => :likes, :source => :user
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :shopping_lists
    has_many :likes
    has_many :liked_vendors, :through => :likes, :source => :vendor
end


class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :vendor
end
```

Comment: when you pass a reference with `render`, here `:vendor => @vendor`, you can use `vendor` without `@` in your partial. So try, `find_by_vendor_id(vendor.id)`

Comment: Hmmm... gave it a shot. Still getting the error. It says it's coming from the `show` action of the Vendors controller.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you should use iteration variable to refer to current vendor (v, not @vendor)

```
<%= render 'layouts/like_button', :vendor => v %>
```

Don't use request to model in view (Vendor.all), it's not MVC-way.
Define it in your controller

```
@vendors = Vendor.all
```

And then refer to it in view

```
@vendors.each do |v|
```

But it still won't be working, as example you mention is not ready-to-use, because it uses authentication system, that is not fully presented in that code. Error you got is also caused by routing as params[:id] was gotten from url.

Comment: Some good points here. I made a few changes at your recommendation. I'm still a bit stuck though. I updated my answer. I'm able to submit `likes` via ajax with the correct parameters, however I still can't `unlike`. Probably something wrong with my destroy action? My page is also not being updated with likes - I still have to refresh the page to see any changes.

Comment: *question, not answer.

Comment: Could you post your models?

Comment: Uncomment line respond_to :js

Comment: You also need unique id for every like in .js and view files as you don't specify which of them rerender.

Comment: In destroy action you ask for like.vendor after deleting the like, not sure it's correct, switch this line with like.destroy

Comment: Hmmm...I'm going to close this question. I think my question is too far away from the solution that it can't really be answered without having to do a complete rewrite. Thanks though. Upvote for the effort.